# DependencyResolver does not exist in the current context when using msbuild

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, msbuild

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection like

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserContext>();
```

which works fine in Visual studio but when I am building project with msbuild I always get this exception:

```
BaseClasses\EntityRepositoryBase.cs (68,40): errorCS0103: The name 'DependencyResolver' does not exist in the current context
```

what can I do? I installed mvc4 again but is the same.

Comment: Are you building the solution directly by using command `msbuild.exe solution.sln` or have you created a specific msbuild target file to build?

Comment: Msbuild ans solution file yes

Answer (score 5):

I think the namespace for DependencyResolver is missing on the file,
add the following to the namespace list

`using System.Web.Mvc;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the first step is to find out what command line arguments and environment variables are passed to msbuild.exe when invoked by the IDE, and how that differs from when you run it directly.  Try the [auto-response file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx) to turn on more detailed logging and log to a file.